# Control 434 MHz US remote outlets without spoofing

Tags: power, remote, wiringpi

I'm looking for hardware or a way to control remote outlets using my Pi, which are compatible to US-outlets and without using a spoofer to set it up.

I tried to use [Etekcity power outlets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQELHBS) like introduced in [this tutorial](https://www.samkear.com/hardware/control-power-outlets-wirelessly-raspberry-pi) but I noticed, that there seems to be a preconfigured and non-changeable code, which separates different outlets and areas. This code is also written on the outlets like f.ex. 0323-1 (*fixed code per set* - *unicode of each outlet (configurable)*). In the tutorial mentioned before (and all others I could find), you are using RFOutlet to send the on/off commands using a special code and pulse which you have to find out before using a 434 MHz-receiver. This special code is always found out in the tutorials by spoofing the conversation between the outlet and the original remote. I couldn't find any reverse engineering to make a association between the code used with RFOutlet and the code written on the outlet / remote.

I would like to find a way to control these remote outlets (or buy other ones), without needing to first spoof the communication between the remote and the outlet using the receiver. Maybe there is a way to convert the labeled code on the outlets & remote to the code which is needed by RFOutlet. Also it would be ok for me, if someone knows another remote outlet-set, which is compatible to US-power-outlets and can be controlled by the Pi / 434-MHz-Transmitter without spoofing.

Comment: I am not sure spoofing is the correct word,but what is your issue with spoofing?

Comment: Im doing this project not for myself, why it's not possible to spoof